# Is there any problem in using Bitnami and Xampp in the same time on one pc?

Tags: django, xampp, bitnami

I guess i miss something,but is there any problem if I use Xampp with PHP&MySQL and Bitnami for Django/Python development.I assigned different ports(80 and 3306 for xampp and 8080 and 3307 for Bitnami).

Comment: There shouldn't be - if you're having a problem, post some information about it (error messages, tracebacks, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

They are actually compatible. (if something like this happens to me, I try with different ports to discover the real problem. Often, ports are being used by other applications which one might not even be really aware of) . We also have a [LAMP](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack) stack that you could use.